# Hashmap value getting updated in all keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having map like this

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

map---> {A=[], B=[], C=[]}

I am trying to add "hai" to key A.
But it is getting added to all key. Below is my code
I am wrong somewhere

```
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry  : map.entrySet()) {
    String a = entry.getKey();
    if(a.equals(attr)){
        List<String> temp = entry.getValue();
        temp.add("hai");
        map.put(a, temp);
        System.out.println("----------"+map);
    }
}
```

output: ------------{A=[hai], B=[hai], C=[hai]}

please suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably filled that map using the same object instance over and over. Please show the code where you fill the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that's happening, maybe as Eran suggested it's in code you aren't showing. However, there's a much easier way to do this instead of iterating through all the keys...

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
...
List<String> values = map.get(attr);
if(values == null) {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(attr, values);
}
values.add("hai");
```

And I'm just guessing here, but I suspect you are doing this to create the array in the first place...

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
map.put("A", values);
map.put("B", values);
map.put("C", values);
```

This causes A, B, and C to all share the same instance of the List. Therefore when you manipulate the list under one key (say, A), you are really making the same change to the lists stored under all keys, because it is the SAME list for all three.

The fix for that is described above, but essentially you want to create a new instance of List for each key in the map.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably putting the same List in all the values of the Map. However, that happens in code you didn't show. When  you put a key in the Map for the first time, make sure you are creating a new List for its value.